# Counting frequently changing values on the database

Tags: sql

I am building a social network site for educational purposes and was wondering how should I efficiently count "tweets" of a user (if for ex. on the tweets table he has 100k entries). Should I do it via SQL Count() or should I add a "no. of tweets" field per user to fetch easily and update it when user add/delete a tweet? Or if there are better approach on this, I'd deeply appreciate your input.

How about the case of counting the total no. of characters of these "tweets"? Is SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(arg)) efficient? Or caching an updated value better?

Let's say these values (no. of tweets and no. of characters for all tweets) are always being called because they are displayed publicly on their profiles, and **on average**, these numbers are getting called once per second and their values change once every 30 seconds.

I am just experimenting on algorithms involving large data, so a big thanks if you can help!

Another thing, is PHP & MariaDB fit for this kind of process? Or other stack are better?

Answer (score 0):

Use the count queries first.  It will most likely be efficient enough given the amount of data (100K) entries. It will also be much less work and maintenance.  100K is a very small number when it comes to database size. When you get to the 100 of millions or billions or more, then things get a bit interesting.

The main consideration for database performance is the database and yes MariaDB or MySql is fine.  What you use for the programming language is a larger question. Php will work fine.